# Convert string of rational number to a variable and back

Tags: strings, variable

How can I convert LaTeX variables and strings when dealing with rational numbers? I have found many working examples for integers, but none for rational numbers.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\stress}{223.032}
\stress
\end{document}
```

Produces the output "223.032". I have found the numprint package to format number strings and append units etc, but how can process the actual value? Something like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\stress}{223.032}
% convert to numeric variable
\stressval=\value{\stress}
% do st with the number
\doublestressval=2*\stressval
% convert to string variable
\doublestress=\tostring{\doublestressval}
% print result
\doublestressval
\end{document}
```

Comment: with the xfp package you can use `\fpeval{2*\stress}`. It is expandable so `\edef\doublestress{\fpeval{2*\stress}}`  will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fairly general method for defining variables and using them. I load `siunitx` for displaying the values, because it's much more powerful than `numprint`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definevars}{m}
 {% #1 = key-value list
  \prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_gluge_vars_prop { #1 }
  \prop_map_inline:Nn \l_gluge_vars_prop
   {
    \fp_zero_new:c { l__gluge_vars_##1_fp }
    \fp_set:cn { l__gluge_vars_##1_fp } { ##2 }
   }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usevar}{m}
 {
  \fp_use:c { l__gluge_vars_#1_fp }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\definevars{
  stress=223.032,
  doublestress=2*\usevar{stress},
  mpv=1.256637062e-6,
}


\begin{document}

The double stress is \qty{\usevar{doublestress}}{\pascal}

The magnetic permeability in vacuum is 
\qty[exponent-mode=scientific]{\usevar{mpv}}{\henry\per\meter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can use as many `\definevars` instructions as you want or need. Of course, if you employ `\usevar` in order to define a new variable, the previous one has to be already defined.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just the siunitx commands throw "undefined control sequence"s but the handling of the rational variables works fine.