Is there any way to replace consecutive 'def'
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\def\aa{11}

\def\bb{22}

\def\cc{33}

\def\dd{44}

% Is there any way to replace above consecutive 'def' by equal sign , such as

aa=11

bb=22

cc=33

dd=44

\aa

\bb

\cc

\dd

% here is method I found from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/629722/convert-string-of-rational-number-to-a-variable-and-back/629726#629726 . but I have to use \usevar function when I need the variable

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definevars}{m}
 {% #1 = key-value list

  \prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_gluge_vars_prop { #1 }

  \prop_map_inline:Nn \l_gluge_vars_prop
   {
    \fp_zero_new:c { l__gluge_vars_##1_fp }

    \fp_set:cn { l__gluge_vars_##1_fp } { ##2 }
   }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usevar}{m}
 {
  \fp_use:c { l__gluge_vars_#1_fp }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\definevars{
  stress=223.032,
  doublestress=2*\usevar{stress},
  mpv=1.256637062e-6
}

% How to read a Variable from a file in LATEX?  .this is also a method , but it needs to write variable to a file in advance.
\end{document}


Might be overkill, but maybe have a look at section 58.2 Assignment of the tikz user manual on how you could do assignments in tikz math.

You start with simple integer assignments but the latter part of the question suggests you are interested in floating point expressions: can you clarify?

I am interested in floating point expressions

It mainly depends on how you'd like to use those values, can you please clarify?

@XCN Of course defining commands without care could lead you to big surprises. Don't.

pyluatex seems more convenient than tikz math.

Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see How do you accept an answer?). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers.

Don't carelessly define commands.
I believe there's a better method: you seem to want numeric variables to make computations with.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definevar}{m}
 {% #1 = comma separated assignments <var>=<value>
  % <var> should be undefined
  \xcn_var_def:n {#1}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\setvar}{m}
 {% #1 = comma separated assignments <var>=<value>
  % <var> should be defined
  \xcn_var_set:n {#1}
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \fp_new_variable:n { V }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \fp_set_variable:nn { V }

\seq_new:N \g__xcn_var_list_seq

\keys_define:nn { xcn/var/def }
 {
  unknown .code:n =
   \fp_new_variable:V \l_keys_key_str
   \seq_gput_right:NV \g__xcn_var_list_seq \l_keys_key_str
   \fp_set_variable:Vn \l_keys_key_str {#1},
 }
\keys_define:nn { xcn/var/set }
 {
  unknown .code:n =
   \seq_if_in:NVTF \g__xcn_var_list_seq \l_keys_key_str
    {
     \fp_set_variable:Vn \l_keys_key_str {#1}
    }
    {
     \msg_error:nnV { xcn/var } { illegal-var } \l_keys_key_str
    }
 }

\msg_new:nnnn { xcn/var } { illegal-var }
 {
  Illegal~variable~'#1'~in~\token_to_str:N \setvar
 }
 {
  The~variable~'#1'~hasn't~been~defined~with~\token_to_str:N \defvar
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \xcn_var_def:n { \keys_set:nn { xcn/var/def } {#1} }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \xcn_var_set:n { \keys_set:nn { xcn/var/set } {#1} }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\definevar{
  aa=11,
  bb=22,
  CC=pi+2,
  DD=bb-CC
}

\begin{document}

\fpeval{aa}

\fpeval{CC+DD}

\fpeval{round(CC-2,4)}

\setvar{aa=-2,pi=3}

\fpeval{aa+2}

\end{document}

I used CC and DD because cc and dd are preempted (they're units used by TeX).
The attempt to use pi in \setvar will be rejected with an error message:
! Package xcn/var Error: Illegal variable 'pi' in \setvar

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...

l.68 \setvar{aa=-2,pi=3}

? h

The variable 'pi' hasn't been defined with \defvar


The output shows that the resetting of aa has been honored.


Excellent suggestion. I wonder how to do it with blank space separated assignments

@XCN Why would you?

Space key is bigger than comma key on keyboard

As usual, fantastic solution! I am wondering if it is possible to add a prefix to the variables used, where aa would be internally registered as xcnaa, and bb as xcnbb, etc. to bypass the collision when using cc.

@M.AlJumaily No, because the idea is to use the new variable inside expressions. I instead added a test in \setvar: if the variable hasn't been defined by \defvar, the setting is disallowed, in order to avoid wrong things such as \setvar{pi=3}

Thank you for the update. Would you suggest using alphanumeric variable names in general?

@M.AlJumaily The present approach might be good for defining parameter, rather than “variables”. Suppose you have several calculations that depend on certain values of some parameters that are selected at runtime. It would be handy to have short names for those parameters. But I'd use different methods for storing computed values.

The following provides what you asked for. For the key=value parsing it uses expkv (disclaimer: I'm the author of that package); the same functionality would also be possible using the expl3 function \keyval_parse:nnn.
Note however that using \def is risky, you should change \def in the definition of \XCNDef to \newcommand (which would tell you for the MWE below that \aa is already defined).
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expkv}

\protected\def\XCNDef{\ekvparse\XCNerr{\ExpandArgs{c}\def}}
\protected\long\def\XCNerr#1%
  {\GenericError{}{Missing value for \detokenize{#1}}{}{}}

\XCNDef{aa=11,bb=22,cc=33,dd=44}

\begin{document}
\aa

\bb

\cc

\dd
\end{document}

Instead of defining those macro names directly you could also use some sort of namespace for your variables (note that TeX has no namespaces, we just use a custom prefix in front of the internal names as a sort of namespace):
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expkv}

\protected\def\XCNDef{\ekvparse\XCNerr\XCNDefAux}
\protected\long\def\XCNDefAux#1{\ExpandArgs{c}\def{XCN var \detokenize{#1}}}
\protected\long\def\XCNerr#1%
  {\GenericError{}{Missing value for \detokenize{#1}}{}{}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\XCNUse[1]
  {%
    \@ifundefined{XCN var \detokenize{#1}}%
      {\ekverr{XCN var}{Undefined variable #1}}%
      {\UseName{XCN var \detokenize{#1}}}%
  }
\makeatother

\XCNDef{aa=11,bb=22,cc=33,dd=44}

\begin{document}
\XCNUse{aa}

\XCNUse{bb}

\XCNUse{cc}

\XCNUse{dd}
\end{document}


It's a nice solution

\XCNDef fails to define variable that contains number, such as a1 b2 etc  . Can this be fixed ?

@XCN the problem is not that it fails to define a command with a number in its name, the problem is that when you then use \a1 what TeX parses is \a and then 1 since under normal conditions numbers can't be part of macro names. If you use the second code with \XCNUse you can use arbitrary names, if you want to use the first solution (I'd advise against it) you can define a1, but have to access it using \UseName{a1}.

OK  I understand

You don't need any special packages. The following three lines defines \eqdef by TeX primitives only.
\def\eqdef#1{\eqdefA#1,,}
\def\eqdefA#1,{\ifx^#1^\else \eqdefB#1,\expandafter\eqdefA\fi}
\def\eqdefB#1=#2,{\expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname{#2}}

\eqdef{aa=11,bb=22,cc=33,dd=44}

\aa

\bb

\cc

\dd

\bye


A nice solution too

@XCN you should notice that there's a difference in behaviour between this code and the one in my answer: \ekvparse strips surrounding whitespace so that aa=11,bb=22 yields the same result as aa = 11, bb = 22. Whichever you prefer is up to you. (also \ekvparse also works with babel and the turkish language package loaded, or active commas)

\eqdef  fails to define variable that contains number, such as  a1  b2  etc

\eqdef doesn't fail if a variable is a1. It defines control sequence a1 with given value. But you cannot use it simply (i.e by \a1) because 1 is not set as letter. The control sequence \a is here followed by 1. Study basic principles of TeX. You can set catcode of 1 as letter but it is very uncommon in TeX.

@wipet this can make it . \eqdef{a3=15,a4=16 } \def\a#1{\csname a#1\endcsname} \a3 \a4

@XCN Yes, but your idea cannot be used in general. If \eqdef{v1=17} is used and \def\v#1{\csname v#1\endcsname} is defined then you cannot use the letter š in 8bit pdflatex because the macro \v is used as an internal macro for creating š here. Using such "short names" for variables and \v for reading such variables is bad concept at all because there are many conflicts with LaTeX's name space. You can do this in OpTeX, for example, because OpTeX's internal name space differs.

@wipet  thank you for reply. I would use it only for experimental purpose .

%pyluatex 

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}

\usepackage[executable=python.exe]{pyluatex}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage[top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,left=1.5cm]{geometry}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\fangsong

\newcommand{\pp}[1]{\pyc{print(#1)}}

\raggedright

\begin{python}

    fc=14.3

    ft=1.43

    fy=360

    fyv=270

    b=250

    h=500

    c=25

    a1=35

    h0=h-a1

\end{python}

\begin{enumerate}[1)]

    \item 
        $h_0=h-a_s=\pp{f'{h}-{a1}={h0}'}$ mm

        $b_{cor}=b-2c=\pp{f'{b}-2\\times{c}={b-2*c}'}$ mm
 
    %\item b

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}


I feel like "integer assignments" (your original example), "floating point expressions" (your later example and a comment), and "input to pyluatex" are all different use cases.  It would have been nice if you'd shown at the start that's what you were interested in.

I thought def command can define both integer and float number
