define element in a list
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\def\test#1{\words#1\relax}

\def\words#1=#2\relax{\expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname{#2}}

\test{er=13965}

\er % for single item \er is well defined

\def\mylist{ee=12,rr=2,yy=3}

\foreach \x in \mylist {\test{\x}\par} % an error occurred

% Runaway argument? \x , ! Paragraph ended before \words was complete.
    
\end{document}


What exactly is your question?

complete \def\ee{12} \def\rr{2} \def\yy{3} in foreach loop

Why you didn't accept the recursive call from my answer from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/728313/ ? All loop macros are based on recursive call because there is no primitive loop in TeX.

I accept your answer. But I also want try other methods.

@XCN As I've already remarked, careless usage of \def can lead to disaster.

You must to give expanded argument to your \test macro, i.e. no \x but ee=12. It means that you must to use \expandafter\test\expandafter{\x} instead of \test{\x}.

But of course, if @XCN use \test{fi=13} then LaTeX crashes. OpTeX is resistant to this.

you can tell \foreach to expand the list before looping. \foreach [expand list=true] ....

however, although this will define the macros \ee etc., doing so is probably pointless since each loop of \foreach forms a local group. i.e. the definitions will not be remembered even from one loop to the next. this does have the advantage of being a bit safer as the deleterious effects of misusing \def will not persist ... provided, of course, you don't redefine anything required to end the loop itself. @wipet's example would still be a very bad idea, for instance.

@XCN as far as I can see, you did not accept any of the answers to the question wipet linked.

You can use the list processing capabilities of etoolbox. Expansion of the argument to \test is performed to allow passing a macro as a list.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\def\cseqval#1=#2\relax{\@namedef{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\test}[1]{%
  % Update how each item will be processed
  \renewcommand{\do}[1]{%
    \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
      \noexpand\cseqval##1\relax}\x%
  }%
  \expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{#1}% Process list
}

\begin{document}

\test{er=13965}

\verb|\er|: \er

\def\mylist{ee=12,rr=2,yy=3}

\test{\mylist}

\verb|\ee|: \ee

\verb|\rr|: \rr

\verb|\yy|: \yy

\end{document}

